# For taking-off and landing in a DHC-7, what elements can be used in writing a novel?

Tags: landing, takeoff, dash-7

What cockpit elements can be used in writing a novel for taking off and landing in a *de Havilland Canada Dash 7* from a short runway in Rothera, Antarctica? Including the names of those switches overhead, and the throttle and the steering stick/wheel?

Comment: You typed Dash 7 in the question but tagged it with Dash 8. Which type are you referring to?

Comment: @kevin There is no Dash-7 tag, probably used that one because it was close.

Comment: Yes, that's why I had to use that Dash-8, it wouldn't let me. It's a de Havilland Canada DASH 7.

Comment: Taking off on a short runway in Antarctica but in good conditions.

Comment: If you want to know what switches are used when, easiest thing to do is to find all the checklists for the Dash 7.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but they're not as basic as what do you call the steering wheel, because I know it won't be the steering wheel!

Comment: Sorry, don't understand this forum very well but thank you to whoever adjusted the tags for me as well as editing my title etc.

Comment: Not specific to the DHC-7, but for general "how do you even land a plane?" research, consider watching some actual-aviation shows. *Air Crash Investigation* isn't bad IMO for the in-cockpit (and in-simulator) scenes, including the terminology used by the pilots. There's also a bunch of videos on Youtube of actual pilots landing actual planes, everything from a tiny GA airplane like a two-seat Cessna up to big jets that fly intercontinental routes with hundreds of passengers. Pay attention to how the flight crew members interact, what they are focusing on, in what order things are done, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
([wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dash_7_Flight_Deck.jpg)) Viewing the full resolution image from the link might help you notice things to use.

1. Steering the yoke right and left controls the aircraft's roll. Pulling/pushing the control column controls the aircraft's pitch (nose up/down).
2. Radio altimeter is used in landing, it offers precise measurement of height above ground.
3. Landing gear lever, down is wheels down.
4. Airspeed indicator shows how fast the plane is going. 12 o'clock position, not going anywhere. Moves clockwise with speed increase.
5. Flaps lever: fully down for take-off/landing from short field.
6. Power levers: push away from you, full power. Pull all the way back, full reverse, which is useful in stopping the plane especially on ice. Don't use the brakes in your novel if the runway is icy.
7. Trim wheel: pilot will use it to fine tune the approach. And after take-off to make pulling the control column easier. You can [watch it on YouTube](https://youtu.be/UFraILWKVLI?t=2m) (head-mounted GoPro).

Comment: Well I didn't find this until now but it is so unbelievably helpful, I just wish I could thank ymb 1 so much for posting this. Although I had written the section, I'm revising it now and I will be able to use the correct terms. I'd done a lot of research but this is the clearest. Thank you so much. I hope this gets to you. Best Evie.

Comment: @EvieMcLaughlin - I'm glad it was helpful :) I did add a link to a video that you might like.

Comment: Where's the cup holder? Surely that will be needed in the novel?